# Current user comments + post title

Tags: comments

I want to show current user comments with the title of the posts in his custom front-end page that I made.

currently I use this code but this only shows the comment itself.

```
    add_shortcode ( 'show_recent_comments', 'show_recent_comments_handler' );

function show_recent_comments_handler( $atts, $content = null )
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        "count" => 10,
        "pretty_permalink" => 0
        ), $atts ));

    $output = ''; // this holds the output

    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
            'number' => $count, // how many comments to retrieve
            'status' => 'approve'
            );

        $comments = get_comments( $args );
        if ( $comments )
        {
            $output.= "<ul>\n";
            foreach ( $comments as $c )
            {
            $output.= '<li>';
            if ( $pretty_permalink ) // uses a lot more queries (not recommended)
                $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
            else

                $output.= '<a href="'.get_settings('siteurl').'/?p='.$c->comment_post_ID.'#comment-'.$c->comment_ID.'">';         
            $output.= $c->comment_content;
            $output.= '</a>';

            $output.= "</li>\n";
            }
            $output.= '</ul>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output.= "<p class='button-com2'>Please login first.</p>";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

I want to show the title of the post, too.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the title of a post if you have the post ID and every comment is assigned to a post ID. So basically, just use the comment_post_ID + get_the_title() function:

```
get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
```

Comment: You're welcome! Vote up the answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: I tried but I can't because voting up needs at lease 15 reputation that I don't have right now. Sorry but Thank you so much.

Comment: But I think you can somehow mark the answer as "right" because you asked the question :)

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Exchange :)